# filtering jquery selection with .not

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

Here is my HTML.

```
  <code>
    <div id="expfield0">

<div class="formrow">
<div class="formlabel"><label for="Memberresumeexp_Company Name">Company  Name</label> </div>
<div class="formtextfield">
<input size="30" maxlength="128" name="Memberresumeexp[0][companyname]" id="Memberresumeexp_0_companyname" type="text" value="" /> 
<span class="error"> </span>

</div>
</div>


<div class="formrow">
<div class="formlabel"><label for="Memberresumeexp_Title">Title</label> </div>
<div class="formtextfield">
<input size="30" maxlength="128" name="Memberresumeexp[0][title]" id="Memberresumeexp_0_title" type="text" value="" /> 
<span class="error"> </span>
</div>
</div>

<div class="formrow">

<div class="formlabel"><label for="Memberresumeexp_Description">Description</label> </div>
<div class="formtextfield">
<textarea name="Memberresumeexp[0][descr]" rows="8" cols="60"></textarea>
</div>


</div> <!-- end expfield0 -->
    <code>
```

In jquery I am trying to select the contents of the div expfield0 and then eliminate the textarea from the selection. It is not working. Here is the jquery snippet.

```
<code>$('#expfield0').not('textarea[name=Memberresumeexp\\[0\\]\\[descr\\]').html()<code>
```

What am I doing wrong here.

Comment: You have asked 5 questions and accepted 0 answers. Why should someone work to help you?

Comment: sorry did not realize that I have to accept answers. I am just thanking people. Will do it right now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are selecting `#expfield0` itself, not its children, so you can't exclude a particular child from the selection.

If you really want to get the HTML of `#expfield0` with the textarea removed, you could do something like this, working on a copy of the element, not the original one:

```
$('#expfield0')
    .clone()
    .find('textarea')
        .remove()
    .end()
    .html();
```